# How to recover "Summary Page Events" folder in Event Viewer (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, event-log

While trying to clear the "Summary Page Events" folder in Event Viewer (Windows 7), I ended up accidentally deleting the folder.

Is there any way to recover/recreate/copy the deleted folder?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can add it to show all critical events such as unexpected shutdowns:

1. On the left-most pane, select "Event Viewer (Local)" (or machinename connected to)

   In the middle pane, you will see a section at the top named "Summary of Administrative Events"

   Right-click on "Critical"

   Select "View All Instances of This Event"

   In the left-most pane, a new Custom View will be created called "Summary page events", and by clicking in it, you will now see the most critical events.

Answer (score 0):

When you first open Event Viewer, you see a "Summary of Administrative Events" in the upper window. Right-click on one of these, e.g. Information, and click View All Instances of this Event. It will create a Summary Page Events.

This may disappear the next time you open Event Viewer, but you can easily create your own Custom View with a similar summary.